# deploying asp.net mvc 3 website

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, deployment

I'm trying to deploy my finished website to the hosting company server and i'm basically stuck. I have  wwwwroot folder on the server where I put my folder of the published project. So what is the index file, the first page that I should display.. is it the layout page or simply my index.cshtml or maybe the _ViewStart? I got to create a path to the folder where the file would be located and give them the name of the "index page". I've been trying to do this for a while now with no luck.

Comment: no, not global.asax, thats not even addressable. use /home/index if they must have something. there is no "whatever.aspx" although tell them it defaults to the index page if they use nothing.

Comment: I used global.asax and it worked

Comment: @AlanBudzinski global.asax is not iis addressable as in you cannot put it in the browser and expect to get that page server, .net specifically ignores this so maybe Im missing what you required. the first page you should display is 100% NOT global.asax. This 'may work' because of something with your routing, but I can guarantee you global.asax should be ever ever be addressed directly. Your default page is listed  on our default route which is /home/index. You may have a catch all  route that leads people there, but

Comment: theres a reason .net doesn't actually want you directly addressing global.asax as its not a served page type.

Comment: ok thanks, i'm gonna change it

Comment: @Adam If you instructed IIS to use Global.asax as your default file, it only "worked" because it doesn't matter in MVC. You could have put MickeyMouse.Ext and gotten the same result.

Comment: @andrewbarber you should never ever point to a file that should never be served. I've seen misconfigured servers during security audits reveal information on these types of files hence my point there's a reason it's not a served page type.

Comment: @Adam I actually meant to direct that comment to Alan, because he seemed to suggest that setting it to Global.asax had "worked". Oops!

Answer (score 1):

Your default route should go to the default controller/view (ie /home/index)
So if someone visits your site at www.yoursitewhatever.com it will automatically find the default page.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a link that might help you and explain the differences between previous MVC versions .

http://haacked.com/archive/2011/05/25/bin-deploying-asp-net-mvc-3.aspx

A default project creates the default page in the global.asax file that is why by default it is located in home/index folder as in 
`routes.MapRoute( "Default", // Route name "{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults );`

Comment: how does this address the default page?

Comment: A default project creates the default page in the global.asax file that is why by default it is located in home/index folder as in    `routes.MapRoute(
            "Default", // Route name
            "{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
            new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults
        ); `

Comment: sure, thats what I stated below before your edit. the article you posted was on deploying, nothing to do with the default document question asked?

Comment: I was trying to provide a helpful link to the question " I'm trying to deploy my finished website to the hosting company server and i'm basically stuck. I have wwwwroot folder on the server where I put my folder of the published project."                                                                                                                               Your are correct about where the location is and my edit. I was trying to explain not just the path but why the default path is the way it is and where it is set. Sorry, I am just getting use to using stack-overflow. Thanks.